# Нужно создать регистрацию + вход.

Tags: php, mysql

Просьба у меня конечно не из легких. Вряд ли кто то поможет сделать, но попытаться стоит.

Если не можете помочь кодом или примером - расскажите хотя бы принцип работы.

Нужно создать регистрацию + вход.

каждому зарегистрированному пользователю должна предоставляться своя страничка (кабинет) и чтоб любой посетитель мог ее просмотреть (даже не зарегистрированный). Но изменять данные на ней, чтобы мог только пользователь, которому страничка принадлежит.

Просьба сильно не обзываться.

Comment: [Только что проверил](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8+php) и оказалось, что google продолжает работать в стандартном режиме. ))

Comment: @Deonis: у них конец света позже наступает, другой часовой пояс.

Answer (score 4):

В базе данных есть таблица Пользователи. В ней есть как-минимум поле Логин, Пароль, ПометкаАктивен и Е-майл (Е-майл можно использовать как Логин, тогда он отдельно не нужен), ну и все поля, которые хотите хранить.

Регистрация - html-форма, в которой пользователь вбивает свой е-майл, два раза пароль и всю прочую чепуху. Когда данные уходят РНР-скрипту, он проверяет, чтоб такого е-майла(+логина если нужно) не было в базе. Если проверка идет по двум полям, то с условием ИЛИ - вам нужно чтоб ни то, ни другое не повторялось.

Если все ок, скрипт делает запись в базе.

Авторизация - в форме только логин и пароль. Если они сходятся с теми, что в базе - то в переменные сессии (на стороне сервера) пишутся данные, под кем мы зашли.

Пароль лучше хранить в базе данные в виде хеша.
Желательно периодически проверять целостность сесси... ну по крайней мере по ИП+штамп браузера.

В принципе почти под все CMS есть готовые решения/модули/плагины. Вам для паблик сайтов стоит юзать их.